# Apple mail 13 push images to left

Tags: macos, email, html-table, html-email

I noticed apple mail 13 (exactly mine Version 13.0 (3608.40.2.2.4)) start push images what size are as big as email itself to left. Some time back it could be solved with align="center" like this:

```
<tr>
    <td algin="center">
        <img src="something.jpg" alt="" width="600" style="width: 600px; max-width: 100%; height: auto;"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

but now its no longer working and its make this:
[image]

I tried body padding 0 and < meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting"/> but without succes. 
Does anybody know how to center that to middle? It is just on apple mail,  other clients are fine.

Comment: It might be useful if you could include a simple yet complete HTML that manifests this problem. I’m not sure if what you’ve provided is quite enough. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What @Rob said is exactly right, more context would help. But first thing to try is to correct your spelling of 'align'. Currently you've got 'algin'

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, the `align=center` fix just made it work for me.